# Killing Spawned Processes when Grunt Exits

Tags: gruntjs

I am currently trying to perform several steps that require tasks to be spawned into child processes.  For example:

1. Watch files
2. Start up my Static Site Generator's Preview Server

I can easily use a tasks like [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) to have both of these run simultaneously.  However, when I exit grunt, the child process (in this case - the static site generator which I am running using [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)) keeps running.  I would like to have these tasks run simultaneously - but also have them be killed when grunt exits.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this works with grunt-shell. But if you'd setup a custom grunt task to run your server you could try somthing like:

```
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var server = spawn('myserver', ['--foo']);
  process.on('exit', function() {
     grunt.log.writeln('killing myserver...');
     server.kill();
     grunt.log.writeln('killed myserver');
  });
```

Comment: I've tried that with no success (no message written or server killed), unfortunately.

Comment: This is the best answer in my taste. simple, straight to the point. no learning curves.. I really support not using libraries if something is THAT simple. Technically, the grunt shell plugin should have done this internally. a simple miss.

Answer (score 0):

is there some reason that you dont use grunt-contrib-connect for starting up a server in your project root?

if possible do this instead of using grunt-shell, and the server will automatically shutdown when your grunt process exits

Comment: Great point - but unfortunately no.  I'm working with Wintersmith as my site generator (which does use a Connect server) - but I want to avoid having to duplicate that logic for the preview server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is why [grunt-exit](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-exit) was created.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `grunt-shell` does not handle `process` exit events: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell/blob/master/tasks/shell.js

Therefore, I suspect that your grunt process is exiting and `grunt-shell` never warns it's child process that the parent process is stopping.

For example, `grunt-concurrent` does kills it's child processes, as we can see here:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
    cpCache.forEach(function (el) {
        el.kill();
    });
});
```

Source: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/blob/master/tasks/concurrent.js#L55

So, using `grunt-shell` won't work for you.

One solution is to require `wintersmith` in your Gruntfile and run it programatically in a custom task.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057486/626810.

This is useful when you have a script that explicitly needs to be invoked (eg: when that process is daemonized).